# Anyone knows what's the machine description mentioned here?

Tags: gcc

> GCC gets most of the information about the target machine from a
>   machine description  which gives an algebraic formula for each of the
>   machine’s instructions.

Anyone knows what's the **machine description** mentioned here?

Comment: From here - http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/gcc_15.html . About GCC and portability.

Comment: @arunkumar ,Yes,it's quoted from there.

Comment: Yes I googled it and found it. I thought the link would be useful. Two lines of a quoted paragraph are not enough to know what you or the quote are talking about. Perhaps you can add the link to your question and change the title to something about GCC and portability if that is what you want to know about.

Comment: @arunkumar ,what I want to know about is high lighted in my post:)

Answer (score 0):

A brief description of the purpose, content and usage of GCC machine descriptions can be found here:

["What is the GCC machine description?](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~uday/courses/cs324-05/gccProjects/node13.html)